# Redirect URI in Google Cloud Console doesn't save

Tags: api, redirect, console, cloud, uri

I have an old OAUTH1 project with a cliend id for web application. The problem is that I can't set redirect URIs. If I update them at https://console.developers.google.com/project/myprojectid/apiui/credential everything seems to be fine. But when I press F5, all the settings are gone. It seems as if Google doesn't store my settings. I have tried it with various browsers but still didn't work.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the redirect URI you are attempting to set? I know it's an annoying question but it could just be in the wrong format...

Comment: it is:  
    https:// subdomain.my-domain.com/login 
    https:// subdomain.my-domain.com/register without the spaces after https://

Comment: Hmmm, is it for a Web Application, Service account or Installed application?

Answer (score 13):

Actually pressing Save twice don't work (at least for me).
Instead, I have to hit enter into textbox. This adds entry into the list.
And only after that clicking Save will save the changes.

Comment: FFS, that is a terrible interface.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Type the redirect URL and press ENTER.
It will get added as a row.
Then click save.

Bad UI Google :( wasted some time trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just an example of poor UX design. I was having the same problem, I would add a redirect URI, click the 'Save' button, see it add a new line, and assume it was saved.

I discovered that the first click of the 'Save' button *only* creates a new line. You have to click the 'Save' button a second time (where it will briefly change the text and color to 'Saving...'), which will save your updates and return you to the previous screen.

Step 1: Enter the URI 
[image: Step 1 - first enter the URI]

Step 2: click 'Save'
[image: Step 2 - Click 'Save' once]

Step 3: Click 'Save' again
[image: Step3]

Answer (score 0):

Authorized redirect URIs not saving. Because of the browser. ***Please change browser to Google chrome or chromium*** which developed by google so we can save it. I faced this problem it has eat the time for my whole day.If changed browser still not working fine, then try to clear everything(history, cache, .....) from the browser.